# How to configure the IIS7 in order to run ASP.net (.aspx) web applications?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, server, localhost

I have configured the `IIS7` and `Application Pools` for my `.aspx` website to run. The application runs fine, but when I click on a link to direct me to another page that I have created, it gives me an error, like the following:
[image]

This is the application pools settings:
[image]

Comment: Are you using URL Routing in your project?

Comment: .NET 4 on IIS 7 or 7.5 requires `aspnet_regiis` to be run.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably missing the Extensionless URL Handler: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4.aspx

Comment: How did configure your website manual or or through VS?

Comment: Is it mvc? If not should it not be About.aspx? Are you using extensionless url handler?

Comment: @LexLi I have run that already.

Comment: @Kev & taleed. I think you guys are right. How do I go about using the "extension less url handler " ???

Comment: @Taleeb Its  C# web app

Comment: I saw the link @Kev posted, but how do I do that? Do I add the code on every page ?